# C# how to get parent class property from child class

Tags: c#, oop, parent-child

Maybe I'm a little dumb, but I need to take the value of the base class parameter from the child class. How can I do that?

My code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnStr)) {
  connection.Open();
  using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Package.StoredProcedure";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(DbParam("in_id", OracleDbType.Int32, id));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(DbOutParam("out_success", OracleDbType.Int32, 1));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int out_success = cmd.Parameters.GetIntValue("out_success");
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

And I wrote extension `GetIntValue` for `OracleParameterCollection`

```
private static int GetIntValue(this OracleParameterCollection parameter, string parameterName) {
  bool success = int.TryParse(parameter[parameterName].Value.ToString(), out int response);
  if (success == false) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"TryParse parameter: {parameterName}");
    throw new Exception("Unhandled Exception");
  }
  return response;
}
```

And I need to get in extension `GetIntValue` property `cmd.CommandText` for printing in Console - How it possible?

Comment: `GetIntValue` takes a `OracleParameterCollection`, which is not a command, so it is unclear which command it would reference. Also, `throw new Exception("Unhandled Exception");` is a really unhelpful exception to throw.

Comment: Please be careful of the tags you use.  Corrected `c` -> `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reference the command, let the extension method accept the command instance, instead of parameters:

```
private static int GetIntValue(this OracleCommand command, string paramName)
{
    var parameters = command.Parameters;

    if (!parameters.Contains(parameterName))
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"{command.CommandText} does not contain param {parameterName}");

    if (!int.TryParse(parameters[paramName].Value.ToString(), out int response))
        throw new FormatException(
            $"could not parse {paramName} in {command.CommandText}");

    return response;
}
```

Note that dumping command texts on exceptions might be a bad idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: Yes it's work well :) But I've wanted to know how to get property off parent class - just for general development :)

Comment: @IgorCova: `OracleParameterCollection` does not expose its parent, you can easily instantiate it on its own, i.e. you could write `new OracleParameterCollection().GetIntValue("something")` and it wouldn't be bound to a command at all. You cannot generally get the parent object of a certain object in OOP (it wouldn't even make sense in many cases since multiple objects can reference the same child instance), unless the child object holds a reference to its parent and exposes it.